# Installing .Net 4.5.2 with Burn error

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.9

I am trying to install .net 4.5.2 as a prerequisite in my Burn Bootstrapper. It installs successfully and requests to restart the computer, on continuation though it gets stuck with a blank .Net upgrade page.

[image]

There are no buttons, and there's no option but to close the installer.

My bootstrapperCore.config is

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<wix.bootstrapper>      
    <host assemblyName="Acquire.InstallerBootstrapper">
        <supportedFramework version="v4.5" />
    </host>
</wix.bootstrapper>
```

And the chain in my bundle contains

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Web"/>
```

Here is the log file generated by Burn:

```
    [0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i001: Burn v3.9.1208.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\simon\Desktop\acQuire GIM Suite Desktop (1).exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{6896412C-53A1-403A-BB71-78CA20BF563B} {25B59D28-FFD7-4900-89FA-2218A21571D1} 1524 /log log.txt'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Initializing string variable 'ProductName' to value 'acQuire GIM Suite Desktop'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Initializing string variable 'DestinationFolder' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]acQuire'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallByDefault' to value 'true'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\simon\Desktop\log.txt'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\simon\Desktop\acQuire GIM Suite Desktop (1).exe'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\simon\Desktop\'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Loading prerequisite bootstrapper application because managed host could not be loaded, error: 0x80070490.
[0348:0120][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '1.1.0.0'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i100: Detect begin, 8 packages
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK45' to value '379893'
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK45 >= 379893' evaluates to true.
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: NetFx452Web, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: Acquire4MsiPackage, state: Absent, cached: None
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: Acquire4MsiPackage, feature: acQuire, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: Acquire4MsiPackage, feature: SentinelDrivers, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: LocalDb, state: Absent, cached: None
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LocalDb, feature: Sql_LocalDB, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LocalDb, feature: Sql_LocalDB_Loc, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LocalDb, feature: SQL_WRITER_LocalDB, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: SQLNCLI, state: Absent, cached: None
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: SQLNCLI, feature: SQL_SNAC_CORE, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: SQLNCLI, feature: SQL_SNAC_SDK, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: LocalDbx86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LocalDbx86, feature: Sql_LocalDB, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LocalDbx86, feature: Sql_LocalDB_Loc, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LocalDbx86, feature: SQL_WRITER_LocalDB, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: SQLNCLIx86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: SQLNCLIx86, feature: SQL_SNAC_CORE, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: SQLNCLIx86, feature: SQL_SNAC_SDK, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: NeoDesktopMsiPackage, state: Absent, cached: None
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: NeoDesktopMsiPackage, feature: Prerequisites, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: NeoDesktopMsiPackage, feature: SQLServerSpatial, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: NeoDesktopMsiPackage, feature: FontsPrereq, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: NeoDesktopMsiPackage, feature: NeoFeature, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: NeoDesktopMsiPackage, feature: NeoHelpFeature, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: NeoDesktopMsiPackage, feature: SupportApplicationFeature, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i101: Detected package: LicenceAdministratorMsiPackage, state: Absent, cached: None
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LicenceAdministratorMsiPackage, feature: LicenceAdminFeature, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i104: Detected package: LicenceAdministratorMsiPackage, feature: LicenceAdminHelpFeature, state: Absent
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i052: Condition 'VersionNT > v5.1' evaluates to true.
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:11:35]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x642
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i000: The prerequisites were already installed. The bootstrapper application will not be reloaded to prevent an infinite loop.
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: DestinationFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\acQuire
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: InstallByDefault = true
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: NETFRAMEWORK45 = 379893
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: ProductName = acQuire GIM Suite Desktop
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: VersionNT = 6.1.0.0
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 1.1.0.0
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 1
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\simon\Desktop\log.txt
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = acQuire Technology Solutions
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = acQuire GIM Suite Desktop
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\simon\Desktop\acQuire GIM Suite Desktop (1).exe
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\simon\Desktop\
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {d1bebfd2-8e17-432f-bf1b-4afd6609579f}
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.1.0.0
[0348:0BC0][2015-04-07T09:13:41]i007: Exit code: 0x642, restarting: No
```

Why is burn complaining that it needs to install the .Net framework, when it is already present?

Comment: Please post the Burn log that's in the %TEMP% directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why :) but with some trial and error changing the bootstrapperCore.Config wix.bootstrapper section to:

```
 <wix.bootstrapper>      
    <host assemblyName="Acquire.InstallerBootstrapper" />
 </wix.bootstrapper>
```

fixed this issue for me.